# Alternative to retired TogetherJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, collaborative-editing, togetherjs

Is there a good alternative to [TogetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/)? Its [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/togetherjs) hasn't had any activity for months, and [this post](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2014/09/professional-transitions.html) says its currently dead with its future uncertain.

The feature most unique to TogetherJS as apposed to say, ShareJS, is the ability to see another person's cursor for use in troubleshooting/remote assistance.

Comment: Did you find anything by any chance? That is a shame it is dying...

Comment: @Nicolas No I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

Try ShareJS, it is similar! 
ShareJS is an Operational Transform library for NodeJS & browsers

http://sharejs.org/

Comment: I guess I should have been more descriptive. TogetherJS's feature of seeing other peoples' cursor.

Comment: Site is down. Did they also died?

Comment: not works the solution proposed